# RegEx for matching yaml files

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the next directory path which contains yaml files:

```
test/1.yaml
test/dev.yaml
test/dev0_r.yaml
```

etc.

How can I match all yaml files which are exactly in test/ directory but not in sub directories like test/test1/dev.yaml

I was trying to use globing:

```
test/*.yaml
```

but it didn't work on https://regex101.com/

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you using shell globbing or regexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, we would be adding a non-slash char class condition after the `test` dir to only pass the first directory, with an expression similar to:

```
^test\/[^\/]+\.yaml$
```

We can add/reduce our boundaries, if we wish so. We could for instance drop the start and end anchors and it might still work:

```
test\/[^\/]+\.yaml
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V8HeHB/1/)

```js
const regex = /^test\/[^\/]+\.yaml$/gm;
const str = `test/1.yaml
test/dev.yaml
test/dev0_r.yaml
test/test1/dev.yaml`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: you should use the `+` quantifier instead of `*`.  +1

Comment: Nice answer  @Emma .